# How to configure docker with pihole for recursive DNS?

Tags: docker, dns, network

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS server for my server where I use Docker to run various applications.

Afterwards I installed unbound and Pihole for Recursive DNS. I changed the Nameserver in the host machine to the ip of the server so it resolves its own DNS.

Problem started when I tried to deploy another docker container. Portainer created a new network for it and I cannot resolve any DNS queries from the docker container. I tried to assign the container to bridge mode but to no avail.

I would like to run docker, pihole for recursive DNS and I want all my other containers to access pihole's DNS server as well. How do I go about doing it?